# Page Header DB Frag ID Property

Tags: sql-server-2012, database-internals, data-pages

I am using SQL Server version: Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.2100.60 (X64).

I created a single table containing one and only one integer-valued column. I then added one and only one row to the table.

```
CREATE DATABASE SQLServerInternals;
GO

USE SQLServerInternals;
GO

CREATE TABLE page_header
(
    c1 INT IDENTITY NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY];
GO

INSERT INTO page_header DEFAULT VALUES;
GO 

DBCC IND(SQLServerInternals,page_header,1);
GO
DBCC TRACEON(3604);
GO
DBCC PAGE (SQLServerInternals,1,231,2);
GO
```

Here is the output from DBCC PAGE.

Does anyone know what the DB Frag ID = 1 means and whether it is the value 0x0100 that I see in bytes 64-65? I assume that the value is at most a SMALLINT type. I assume that the remaining bytes are for "future use".

[image]

Comment: I've not stumbled upon "DB Frag ID" before, it would seem that's new to 2012. However, looking at the header for 2008R2 and earlier, only bytes 0-63 are in use:

 https://github.com/improvedk/OrcaMDF/blob/master/src/OrcaMDF.Core/Engine/Pages/PageHeader.cs

Thus, if they added a new property, it would make sense for it to be in bytes 64+

Comment: Altering the 65th byte on the page in a test database doesn't seem to affect anything reported by `DBCC PAGE`. It still says `DB Frag ID = 1` regardless of what I set it to

Comment: @MarkS.Rasmussen I too have never seen "DB Frag ID" before. I assume it has nothing to do with index fragmentation. Maybe database fragment...? I have no clue.

Comment: @MarkS.Rasmussen  I just came across [this connect item](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/809968/dac-abbruch-select-from-sys-sysrscols) that points out that `sys.sysrscols` used to have a column called `dbfragid` but this no longer exists in 2012. So I wonder if it was always there. Just changed location.